android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException | Error inflating AppWidget
AppWidgetHostView       ...                        W  Error inflating AppWidget
AppWidgetProviderInfo(UserHandle{0}/ComponentInfo{....widgets.SmallWidget}): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
Launcher.Widget         ...
E  widget load error:AppWidgetProviderInfo(UserHandle{0}/ComponentInfo{....widgets.SmallWidget})
WidgetCheckManager      ...
I  updateCurrentWidget, userId is 0, widgetUidSet: [10177, 10181, 11128, 11244, 10303]
When I try to run my widgets in Android, I get this error. It says widgets assets are not found. But my assets are kept in place. How can I resolve this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
